# shorten code range array elements

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, sum, addition

How can I shorten this code?
I also tried `SUM` on a range of array elements but that didn't worked because I don't know the correct syntax.
Thanks in advance.

```
Workbooks("items.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, 107).Value = _
arr(r, 4) + arr(r, 5) + arr(r, 6) + arr(r, 7) + arr(r, 8) + arr(r, 9) 
+ arr(r, 10) + arr(r, 11) + arr(r, 12) + arr(r, 13)
+ arr(r, 14) + arr(r, 15) + arr(r, 16) + arr(r, 17) 
+ arr(r, 18) + arr(r, 19) + arr(r, 20) + arr(r, 21) 
+ arr(r, 22) + arr(r, 23) + arr(r, 24) + arr(r, 25) 
+ arr(r, 26) + arr(r, 27) + arr(r, 28) + arr(r, 29) 
+ arr(r, 30) + arr(r, 31) + arr(r, 32) + arr(r, 33) 
+ arr(r, 34) + arr(r, 35) + arr(r, 36) + arr(r, 37) 
+ arr(r, 38) + arr(r, 39) + arr(r, 40) + arr(r, 41) 
+ arr(r, 42) + arr(r, 43) + arr(r, 44) + arr(r, 45) 
+ arr(r, 46) + arr(r, 47) + arr(r, 48) + arr(r, 49) 
+ arr(r, 50) + arr(r, 51) + arr(r, 52) + arr(r, 53) 
+ arr(r, 54) + arr(r, 55)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could sum the `r'th row` entirely of the array using `SUM` and `INDEX` with the following:

```
Workbooks("items.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, 107).Value = _
  Application.Sum(Application.Index(ar, r))
```

But since you want to sum only a chunk of the row, columns 4 to 55:

```
Workbooks("items.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, 107).Value = _
  Application.Sum(Application.Index(ar, r, [Row(4:55)]))
```

Simplest, implement a `For` loop, i.e.

```
Dim sum as double, i as long
For i = 4 to 55 : sum = sum + arr(r, i) : Next
Workbooks("items.xlsm").Sheets(1).Cells(r, 107).Value = sum
```

Comment: the `For` loop works very well. Also the notation with colon is new for me. Nice and short.